# UITableViewCell unexpected behaviour

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uistoryboard

I have a `UITableViewCell` with multiple `UILabels` one of them is multi-line. All `UILabels` has a fixed spacing with `content hugging and compression resistance` as mentioned in the picture attached below.

[image]

In the code, `tableView` and is a `delegate` and `dataSource` with `rowHeight` property and `heightForRowAt` set to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

I tried shuffling and making various arrangements with `content hugging and compression resistance` values. But the height of the smaller cell with lesser text keeps the same size(as in the picture below) and the cell with more text appears just like it is supposed to be. 
I haven't mentioned any height except `estimatedRowHeight` i.e., 135

I made a height check with

```
print(cell.frame.height)
```

It return `140.0` for all cells.

Resultant looks like this:

[image]

Comment: For "Bucharest Marathon" label, set the vertical content hugging to be .required `label.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)` or 1000. When you set it means that label wouldn't be stretched vertically beyond it's intrinsic height

Comment: @user1046037 I changed `contentHuggingPriority` vertical to 1000 for all `UILabels` and it's working as expected. Is that normal, I need to get my head around this. If you will post this as an answer, I will accept. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Concept:

**ContentHugging Resistance**: When you set a priority it corresponds to how much the view must resist the content being stretched.

For example: If content hugging priority for vertical axis is set as 1000 or .required, then it means that the view will not be stretched beyond it's content height. So if the label has 1 line, then it wouldn't be stretched beyond the height of that 1 line.

**Content Compression**: It is just the opposite, it would resist the view from compressing the content of the view.

## Solution:

For "Bucharest Marathon" label, set the vertical content hugging to be .required.

### Code:

`label.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)` or `1000`

Comment: My savior! Thank you. `❤️`

Comment: Glad it helped you, just a small note, in such a scenario use a `UIStackView`, as it would help you manage multiple views.